# Removing Characters from a string if span is not empty using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html code:

```
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4 propertyprice_display"><strong>Price:</strong> 
<span class="price_label price_label_before">USD </span> UGS 6,000 
<span class="price_label">per month</span></div>
```

**Price:** 
      UGS 6,000 
    per month

That is displayed as `Price: USD UGS 6,000 per month`

I am wondering if its actually possible to remove UGS if the span `price_label price_label_before` if not empty. If empty, UGS should not be removed using jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var spanText = $('.price_label_before').text().trim();
if(spanText !== null){
var nHTML = $('.propertyprice_display').html();
nHTML = nHTML.replace('UGS','');
$('.propertyprice_display').html(nHTML)
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4 propertyprice_display"><strong>Price:</strong> 
<span class="price_label price_label_before">USD </span> UGS 6,000 
<span class="price_label">per month</span></div>

 <div class="listing_detail col-md-4 propertyprice_display"><strong>Price:</strong> 
<span class="price_label price_label_before"> </span> UGS 7,000 
<span class="price_label">per month</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html

```
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Price:</strong> 
<div class='emptyclass'>
<span class="price_label price_label_before"> </span> UGS 6,000 
<span class="price_label">per month</span></div>
</div>
```

Your JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($('.price_label_before').html().trim()=="")// check if span is empty
{
     $('.emptyclass').html('');//if yes then emtpty div
}
else
{
    //your else defination
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to wrap the text that may need to be removed in its own `span` element for easy removal, but assuming that you need to keep the HTML structure as is, you can access the plain text that is not wrapped by extracting a DOM node reference from the JQuery wrapped set of elements when needed.

Please see the comments in the code below for explanations:

```js
// Just passing a function to the JQuery shortcut identifier: $ is the same
// thing as: $(document).ready(function()...
$(function() {
 // Get reference to the element to check:
 var $spanToCheck = $(".price_label.price_label_before");
  
 // Check the element's text:
 if ($spanToCheck.text() !== "") { 
   // Get reference to the text node that comes after the span. Note the [0] which 
   // extracts an element from the JQuery wrapped set and returns a regular DOM node:
   let nodeToFix = $(".price_label.price_label_before")[0].nextSibling;
   
  // Correct the node value of the node
   nodeToFix.nodeValue = nodeToFix.nodeValue.replace("UGS", "");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Price:</strong> 
  <span class="price_label price_label_before">USD </span> UGS 6,000 
  <span class="price_label">per month</span></div>

  <div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Area:</strong> 
  <span class="">10sqm </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but i get the error caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Comment: @user38208 Then you have different code than you've posted. As you can see by running the code snippet above, it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to achieve what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var spanText = $('.price_label.price_label_before').text().trim();
  if(spanText !== ''){
    var nHTML = $('.listing_detail').html();
    nHTML = nHTML.replace('UGS','');
    $('.listing_detail').html(nHTML)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Price:</strong> 
<span class="price_label price_label_before">USD </span> UGS 6,000 
<span class="price_label">per month</span></div>
```

Comment: This will replace every occurrences of `UGS` within the whole HTML.

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal. I tried this solution as well but it doesnt seem to work because even when `<span class="price_label price_label_before">` is empty UGS is still replaced.